# Cross-platform solution to isolated storage in PCL?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, isolatedstorage, portable-class-library

I'm currently using the latest version of PCLStorage for my Xamarin app and it doesn't work well in Android. Every time my app loads it is unable to find the directory I had just created. But it works fine in my Windows project. Odd...

Does anyone know of a good alternative compatible with Portable Class Libraries?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the code I use:

These are the functions that save/load the data:

```
 public static async Task<bool> LoadPlayerData()
 {
    PlayerData data = await LoadData<PlayerData>("PlayerState.dat");

    if (data != null)
    {
        PlayerData.Current = data;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
 }

 public static async Task SavePlayerData()
 {
    IFolder dataFolder = await GetDataFolder(true);
    IFile file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("PlayerState.dat", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    string json = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PlayerData.Current, Formatting.Indented));
    await file.WriteAllTextAsync(json);
 }
```

These are the functions that do the work using PCLStorage:

```
    private static async Task<T> LoadData<T>(string filename)
    {
        IFolder dataFolder = await GetDataFolder(false);

        if (dataFolder == null)
            return default(T);

        IFile file = null;

        try
        {
            // Catch the exception if the file doesn't yet exist
            file = await dataFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        }
        catch (PCLStorage.Exceptions.FileNotFoundException) { return default(T); }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException) { return default(T); }

        if (file == null)
            return default(T);

        string contents = await file.ReadAllTextAsync();

        T data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(contents);

        return data;
    }

    private static async Task<IFolder> GetDataFolder(bool createIfNonExistent)
    {
        IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFolder dataFolder = null;

        // Save actions will create the folder if it doesn't exist. Load actions will only try to get the folder.
        if (createIfNonExistent)
            dataFolder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("GameData", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Catch the exception if the folder doesn't yet exist
                dataFolder = await rootFolder.GetFolderAsync("GameData");
            }
            catch (PCLStorage.Exceptions.DirectoryNotFoundException) { return null; }
        }

        return dataFolder;
    }
```

Everything runs fine in my Windows 8 project, but in Android, when trying to load the data which was just created (for example, when re-starting the app), I always get a **DirectoryNotFoundException** in my **GetDataFolder** function.

**UPDATE 2**

On the **SavePlayerData** function I get a successful file creation since it contains the following path:

> /data/data/com.quickshift/files/GameData/PlayerState.dat

When I restart my app, the **GetDataFolder** function fails when calling **rootFolder.GetFolderAsync(...)** with the following message:

> Directory does not exist: /data/data/com.quickshift/files/GameData

I'll keep looking into this, it used to work a few weeks ago and I never changed this code...

Comment: As the project is open source, did you consider forking it and seeing what the problem is? Could be faster than finding an alternative and a good way to get more familiar with the insides of a project you are using. Just a thought! I did fork the project myself and will investigate how good/mature it is. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post more information about how you are using PCL Storage and how it is failing?  I know that there are others who are using it successfully on Android

Comment: @SKall: Thanks, that's a great idea I didn't think of it  :)

Comment: @DanielPlaisted: I updated my post with the code that I'm using. Am I doing something wrong???

Comment: @MassimoCacchiotti I didn't find anythnig that stood out as wrong with the code.  It sounds like saving the data is working correctly but you get an error loading, is that correct?  Can you post the stack trace of the failure and which lines of the GetDataFolder and other methods it's failing on?

Comment: Added my error messages, I'll keep looking into this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the folder wouldn't exist.  Can you look at the file system on the device/emulator to see if the data file is there after the first run?

If the folder doesn't exist, it looks like your GetDataFolder method should return null instead of letting the exception through.  It sounds like the GetDataFolder method is not catching the DirectoryNotFoundException thrown from GetFolderAsync().  Can you try changing the catch block to catch IOException or Exception instead of PCLStorage's DirectoryNotFoundException, and see if that changes the behavior?

Is the exception being thrown from the first line of LoadData where it calls GetFolderAsync(false)?

Comment: Daniel, where can i find the folder? Does the data get saved in the sdcard folder or root folder? In other words, the path i mentioned above is relative to the root or sdcard folder?

Comment: @MassimoCacchiotti Sorry, I don't know too much about Android development, so I don't know exactly where the data gets saved or how to browse it.